# Using Navigation Drawer List in Tablayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using a navigation drawer that fetches the album list from picasa web api. I have been trying to implement that same list as the tab items. Can someone please help me with implementing it?

This is the Navigation Drawer item class to show the albums in the navigation drawer.

```
public class NavDrawerItem {
    private String albumId, albumTitle;
    // boolean flag to check for recent album
    private boolean isRecentAlbum = false;

    public NavDrawerItem() {
    }

    public NavDrawerItem(String albumId, String albumTitle) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
        this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
    }

    public NavDrawerItem(String albumId, String albumTitle,
                         boolean isRecentAlbum) {
        this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
        this.isRecentAlbum = isRecentAlbum;
    }

    public String getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public void setAlbumId(String albumId) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.albumTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.albumTitle = title;
    }

    public boolean isRecentAlbum() {
        return isRecentAlbum;
    }

    public void setRecentAlbum(boolean isRecentAlbum) {
        this.isRecentAlbum = isRecentAlbum;
    }
}
```

Nav drawer list adapter

```
    package com.techsprint.wallpaperpro.helper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.techsprint.wallpaperpro.NavDrawerItem;
import com.techsprint.wallpaperpro.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Mahe on 6/18/2015.
 */
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,
                                ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The activity main layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_view_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_view_divider_height"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Drawer item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_list_item_layout_height"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_list_item_layout_height"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navimage_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_subject_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navimage_list"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_list_item_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/drawer_list_item_padding"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_title" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Navigation drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private List<Category> albumsList;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // Getting the albums from shared preferences
        albumsList = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger().getCategories();

        // Insert "Recently Added" in navigation drawer first position
        Category recentAlbum = new Category(null,
                getString(R.string.nav_drawer_recently_added));

        albumsList.add(0, recentAlbum);

        // Loop through albums in add them to navigation drawer adapter
        for (Category a : albumsList) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(a.getId(), a.getTitle()));
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // Setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        /*getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.transparent)));*/
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String HARDWARE = Build.HARDWARE;
    String TYPE = Build.TYPE;
    String board = Build.BOARD;


    /**
     * Navigation drawer menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * On menu item selected
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
       /* if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }*/
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // Selected settings menu item
                // launch Settings activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.googleplus:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GooglePlusActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            case R.id.feedback:
                final Intent _Intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                _Intent.setType("text/html");
                _Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getString(R.string.mail_feedback_email)});
                _Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.mail_feedback_subject));
                _Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please Leave Your Valuable Feedback Above This Line" + "\n" + deviceMan + " " + deviceName + "," + " " + HARDWARE + "," + " " + board + "," + " " + TYPE);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(_Intent, getString(R.string.title_send_feedback)));
                return true;

            case R.id.followus:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FollowUsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
            case R.id.test:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Recently added item selected
                // don't pass album id to grid fragment
                fragment = GridFragment.newInstance(null);
                break;

            default:
                // selected wallpaper category
                // send album id to grid fragment to list all the wallpapers
                String albumId = albumsList.get(position).getId();
                fragment = GridFragment.newInstance(albumId);
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(albumsList.get(position).getTitle());
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

The application is a wallpaper app which fetches data from the picasa web api. The app uses the volley library.

Comment: Do you want to use one list view in two places?

Comment: yes, i want to to display the items on the drawer in the tab layout.